# how to add NSString from loop in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I want to add NSString Name in NSmutableArray but I dont know about that.
I get 5 NSString name from url in wamp server and I want add these names in NSMutableArray.

this is my code but do not work!!! :

```
    NSMutableArray *file;
for (int j=0; j < 5; j++) {
        NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.101/janatan/filemanager.php?dir=root&file=%d&name",j]]];
        NSLog(@"%@",fileName);
        [file addObject:fileName]  //right???
    }
```

Comment: alloc]init]; your NSMutableArray.

Comment: Do you like to add same filename for 5 times?

Answer (score 4):

You are not allocating `NSMutableArray`

```
NSMutableArray *file = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
```

If you are not sure about the number of elements gets added to array beforehand, you can use

```
NSMutableArray *file = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the `NSMutableArray` must be allocated.

Secondly, the using of [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) must be avoided.

Next, the readability of code should be improved by replace

```
NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.101/janatan/filemanager.php?dir=root&file=%d&name",j]]];
```

to something more convenient. Moreover, the memory here is allocated but never released.

Your code may be as follows:

```
const int numberOfFiles = 5;
NSMutableArray *file = [NSMutableArray array]
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; ++i){
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.101/janatan/filemanager.php?dir=root&file=%d&name", i]];
      NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
      [file addObject:fileName];
 }
```

But here are we can find some problems.
For example if url is changed on server-side you'd rewrite the code. If the number of elements is changed it's the same. So it would be good to find a way to avoid this kind of dependence.